# Trying to add a stroke around a PNG, can it be improved?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to find a good way to add a 3px white stroke to a ton of png files, effectively to make them look like "stickers." I've got some sample code that does a decent job, but I can't seem to get the cropping right. Also, the stroke looks a bit pixelated and I wanted to know if it's possible to get cleaner edges!

I did a bunch of internet scouring, found some sample code, tweaked it around, and came to something that almost resembles what I'm looking for. The images are always going to be PNGs, so I looked into things like inkscape/gimp from the command line but realized I should be able to do this just using `convert` from the terminal.

```
convert in.png \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract -threshold 0 \) \
\( -clone 1 -blur 10x65000 -threshold 0 \) \
\( -clone 2 -fill red -opaque white \) \
\( -clone 3 -clone 0 -clone 1 -alpha off -compose over -composite \) \
-delete 0,1,3 +swap -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
out.png
```

in: [image: in.png]

out: [image: out.png]

ideally:
[image: ideally.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is it is that you do not have enough space bettween your object and the sides of the image. You just need to add your image with transparency and then remove any excess later.

In ImageMagick 6, this should do what you want.

[image]

```
1) read the input
2) add a larger border than you need to add
3) extract the alpha channel from the input and dilate it by the amount of border (in this case 10)
4) copy the previous image and color the white as red and the black as transparent
5) composite the original over the red/transparent image
6) delete the original and the red/transparent image
7) swap the composite with the dilated alpha channel and put the dilated alpha channel into the alpha channel of the previous image
8) trim the excess transparency from the border padding
9) save to output

convert img.png \
-bordercolor none -border 20 \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract -morphology dilate diamond:10 \) \
\( -clone 1 -fuzz 30% -fill red -opaque white -fill none -opaque black \) \
\( -clone 2,0 -compose over -composite \) \
-delete 0,2 \
+swap -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
-trim +repage \
result.png
```

[image]

For ImageMagick 7, replace convert with magick.

If on a Unix-like system, you might be interested in my bash ImageMagick script, contour, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

A better result can be achieved by replacing diamond:10 with disk:10

[image]

Comment: This is pretty darn close. I actually used this and just changed the morphology from diamond:10 to octagon:4 and it looks a bit better (you can see in yours the bottom left looks a bit funky).

Comment: Feel free to modify it as desired. Note my edit at the top of my answer. I modified my answer to show the same but using disk:10 rather than diamond:10

Comment: why this command make black shadow , can a way to hidden black shadow?

Comment: What black shadow?